# How to reference another range or cell as a string argument in query?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

1.2.3 are working just fine because the operation is this:

```
=QUERY({'ALL Leads'!$A:$R};"SELECT Col3 WHERE Col15= 'Zohra'";"")
```

Now I want it to get me whatever is in column E10 ("Zohra" in this example) but apparently it's not working !

What do you think the problem is?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY({'ALL Leads'!$A:$R}; "select Col3 where Col15 = '"&E10&"'"; )
```

extra advice: if E10 would be numeric number formula would be:

```
=QUERY({'ALL Leads'!$A:$R}; "select Col3 where Col15 = "&E10; )
```

Comment: @MO396 answer updated